# MySQL query error

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

Can someone help me correct the following error I keep getting when trying to run my MySQL query.

Here is my error.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE user_id = '3' AND id = '3' AND friendship_status = '0'' at line 2
```

Here is my mysql code.

```
SELECT users_friends.*
WHERE user_id = '$user_id'
AND id = '$request_id'
AND friendship_status = '0'
```

Comment: Where is `from` after `SELECT`?

Comment: duh, I just noticed my error thanks. Don't code in the late night

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably need to add: `FROM users_friends` just before the `WHERE`.

```
SELECT  users_friends.*
FROM    users_friends
WHERE   user_id = '$user_id'
AND     id = '$request_id'
AND     friendship_status = '0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

(PHP assumed)

```
 $string = "SELECT from  database_name.table_name 
            WHERE user_id ='".$user_id."' AND id= '".$request_id."'
            AND friendship status ='0' ";
```

I have assumed that `$user_id` and `$request_id` are of `varchar/text` type